# Adding -s or -ed at the end of verb

Tags: verbs, present-tense

I have a present tense sentence where I can't tell if adding -s or -ed at the end of verb.

The sentence goes like this :

> He falls down right after he gets the kite causing his leg to injure.

The *injure* word here, should it be added by **-s** since it is referring to *leg* which is singular and synchronized with the present tense sentence? Or should it be in a past tense form because he gets the injury *right after* he gets the kite?

Comment: Neither is correct.  "To injure" means *to cause injury to something else*.  So when you say "his leg injures", that means his leg is hurting *something else*.  What you want is the passive voice: "...causing his leg to be injured."

Comment: @stangdon Correct me if I'm wrong. Based on your explanation, I seem to understand the usage now when you are mentioning the passive voice. So basically, when we say something in present tense form and there is a change in a state caused by a certain action, then we need to change the verb to a past tense. Is it something like that?

Comment: Almost correct: we use the passive voice when we want to talk about something being acted on by something else, and we use the *past participle*.  So for example, *they **ate** the cake*, but *the cake **was eaten***.

Comment: Great! that's easy for me to understand. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verbs **falls** and **gets** are in 3rd-person singular present tense. You are correct.

However, the verb **injure** cannot be used like that. The leg **becomes injured**.

> He falls down right after he gets the kite, injuring his leg.
>
> He falls down right after he gets the kite and injures his leg.

Answer (score 1):

This is an infinitive (signalled by the infinitive marker *to*), so it does not take any inflectional suffix for person or tense.

However, we do not say that someone or something *injures* to mean that it "receives" an injury. This may be expressed either with another subject, as in Tᴚoɯɐuo's Answer, or with *leg* as subject in the passive voice, as stangdon says in a Comment.

The passive requires an auxiliary, formally *BE* or informally *GET*, and it is that which is cast in the infinitive, followed by the passive participle form of *injure*. With *injure*, a regular verb, this form happens to be identical with the past form, but this is not always the case, so we have to distinguish between past participle and past-tense forms:

> . . . causing his leg to **be injured**, *but*
>   . . . causing his leg to **be broken**.